# list manipulation error and append

Tags: python

I am a python beginner and have been having trouble understanding this code.

```
my_list = [12, "cat", 3.4, "dog", 62]
new_list = []

for k in range(5):

    if k % 2:
        m = my_list.pop(k)
        new_list.append(m)

print(new_list)
```

As my understanding the result should be [12,62]
But it says ['cat',62]

Can anyone explain it to me? 
It will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what are the numbers in `range(5)`? 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, right?

Which of those are odd? (that is, `k % 2` is nonzero and therefore "truthy") 1 and 3, right?

So, you first take item 1, "cat", and remove it from the original list and add it to the new list. The original list is now:

```
[12, 3.4, "dog", 62]
```

Now you take item 3, 62, and remove it from the original list and add it to the new list.

We have added "cat" and 62 to the new list, which started out empty. Therefore the new list is

```
["cat", 62]
```

The original list is:

```
[12, 3,4, "dog"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Extremely helpful

Answer (score 1):

Lists are zero indexed in Python. So `my_list[0] == 12`, `my_list[1] == 'cat'`, etc.

The loop `for k in range(5):` steps so that `k` gets the values `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` (the end is exclusive, so `k` is never going to be `5`.

`if k % 2:` means, "whenever `k` modulo 2 is non-zero", which is equivalent to "when `k` is odd". The first odd value that `k` gets is `1`. `my_list[1]` is `"cat"`, so that gets appended to `new_list` first.

`list.pop` removes and returns an element from the list. This means that once `k == 1` has been processed, `"cat"` is no longer in the list. `my_list` will be `[12, 3.4, "dog", 62]` after that.

The next odd number is `3`. `my_list[3]` is now `62`. If `"cat"` had not been removed, it would have been `"dog"` instead. `my_list` will be `[12, 3.4, "dog"]` after that.

Now comes the crucial part: The last value of `k` is `4`. Fortunately, 4 is even, so the `if` is not entered. If it had been, there would be an error because `my_list` only has 3 elements left, and you can't pop the 5th element (index 4) off.

Answer (score 0):

`if k % 2:` is `True` if `k` is odd.

When `k=0` it will not go inside `if`

when `k=1` it goes inside `if` and pops->cat

now list is

```
list [12, 3.4, "dog", 62]
```

and

```
 new_list=["cat"]
```

when `k=2` it will not go inside `if`

when `k=3` it goes inside if and pops `62`

so `new_list = ["cat","62"]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's walk through step by step:

```
my_list = [12, "cat", 3.4, "dog", 62] # (List of 5 Elements)
new_list = [] # (Empty List)
for k in range(5): # A For loop from 0 to 4 ## value of K goes from 0 to 4

    if k % 2: # Checking whether k is odd 
              # Here k%2 return  0 (if k is even ) or 1 (if K is odd)
              # So, Here, if k % 2: condition works only on odd Numbers i.e. [1,3]

        m = my_list.pop(k) # The method pop() removes and returns last object or obj from the list. 
         # this return and remove element on index k
         # Here, when value of k is 1, return element 'cat' at index 1 in my_list
         # and update the my_list ! now my_list is [12, 3.4, 'dog', 62]
         # When value of k is 3, return element 62 on index 3 in updated list [12, 3.4, 'dog', 62]
         # again update the my_list to [12, 3.4, 'dog']

       new_list.append(m) # Append the element in List
                          # First m contains 'cat' and then 62
print(new_list) # Print the list which is ['cat',62]
```